# How should one show possession in "and I" constructions?

Tags: possessives

I share an office with a co-worker and wanted to write something about the office that she and I share. Should I do something like one of these:

- Stacey's and I's office
- Stacey and I's office

?

Comment: *Mine and Stacey's office.*

Answer (score 1):

As *I* is the subject personal pronoun, it is best used when Stacey and you are the subject of the verb.

- Stacey and I share this office.

As *Stacey's* in your example has a possessive meaning, a possessive pronoun makes most sense here.

- Stacey's and my office

Having said that,

- the office Stacey and I share

(only slightly modified from your question) is probably easier for most listeners or readers to parse.